# Mathematica Function Taxicab Numbers

Tags: functions, scoping, conditional, infinite-loop

I have spent days trying to compile this code and I cannot generate a list of taxicab numbers for the Hardy-Ramanujan Theory. Here is the module I wrote earlier:

```
Ramamanujan_Number[N_] := 
 Module[{taxicablist = [], int_count = 0, i, j, k}, 
  For[i = 0, i < N, i++; 
   For[j = 1, j < N - 1, j++; For[k = 1, k < N - 1, k++; 
     If[j^3 + k^3 == i, int_count += 1]];
    If[int_count == 2, AppendTo[taxicablist, i];
     ]]]]
Print[taxicablist]

Ramananujan_Number[10000]
```

What minor changes do I need to make in order to generate a list in this function?

Comment: you should get rid of underscore (`_`) in variable and function names. `_` has a built-in meaning in wolfram language. See [Blank (_)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html) in the docs.

Comment: Change `i++;` to `i++,` and `j++;` to `j++,` and `k++;` to `k++,` and `taxicablist = []` to `taxicablist = {}` and spell `Ramananujan` the same way both times. You might think carefully about your lower and upper bounds on each `For` loop because I believe your code thinks that 9 can be written as 1^3+2^3 and as 2^3+1^3 and thus qualifies. You might also be able to speed the code up by not looking at cubes up to (N-1)^3 in size.

Comment: Look at the Mathematica program found here: https://oeis.org/A001235